# run lsof in non-interactive mode

Tags: lsof

I need to write `lsof` output for several network ports into bash variable.

Simple `$(lsof -i :5555)` doesn't work - lsof waits for quit command (Ctrl-C) every time I call it.

I can't figure out how to solve my task.

Comment: More details, e.g. what OS? What happens if you run lsof as a single command? It works here on Ubuntu 12.04 and CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Usually when `lsof` takes a long time to complete it is because DNS resolution takes too long. Could that be it? Try adding `-n`

Comment: @VictorMezrin great, I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A long running `lsof` process usually means that DNS resolution is timing out or not working correctly which is delaying the output of it.
You can disable DNS resolution by adding the `-n` option.

Of course you might want to check out why DNS resolution is taking too long on your server as well.